Making BaCl2 solution without knowing the solution density
Problem = make 10 wt% BaCl2 solution with BaCl2(dihydrated).
Can I know how many grams of Bacl2 to put in without knowing the density of the solution?
My friend solved it with the attached photo.
244.26 = dihydrated BaCl2 g/mol
208.23 = anhydrous BaCl2  g/mol
I can't understand her formula. 1.17 means the density


You need not solution density or volume. All is about weights. You need the weight of dihydrate equivalent to 10 g of anhydrous BaCl2, Then you take weight of water (or eq. volume) as complement to 100 g.

1.17 is not density, but weight conversion ratio between two BaCl2 forms.

$100$ g anhydrous $\ce{BaCl2}$ is contained in $117.3$ g $\ce{BaCl2·2H2O}$. So take this amount of $\ce{BaCl2·2H2O}$ and dissolve it in $882.7$ g pure water. This will produce $1000$ g of a $10$ weight % $\ce{BaCl2}$ solution. The final obtained volume is not known.
